# Kotlin, JPA and @Transient

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, kotlin

I have an Entity class that I have migrated from Java to Kotlin. One of the properties (`inetAddress`) is annotated with `@Transient` to prevent it from being persisted to the relational database. However, JPA (Hibernate implementation) does not see this annotation and places it in the database as it's own field. This all works properly when the class is written in Java.

Does anyone known how to properly annotate this Kotlin class so that JPA/Hibernate will see the `@Transient` annotation and not place the `inetAddress` property in the database?

```
package infr.audio.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import infr.audio.messages.InetAddressWrapper
import java.io.Serializable
import java.net.InetAddress
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "DIS_JOCKEY")
@NamedQueries(NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.find", query = "SELECT m FROM DisJockeyInfo m"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.findByReservationId", query = "SELECT m FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.reservationId = :reservationId"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.findByReservationIdAndName", query = "SELECT m FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.reservationId = :reservationId AND m.name = :name"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.findMaxDisEntityIdByReservationId", query = "SELECT MAX(m.disEntityId) FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.reservationId = :reservationId"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.findActive", query = "SELECT m FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.disEntityId IS NOT NULL"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.findActiveByInetAddress", query = "SELECT m FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.inetAddress = :inetAddress AND m.disEntityId IS NOT NULL"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.findActiveByReservationId", query = "SELECT m FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.reservationId = :reservationId AND m.disEntityId IS NOT NULL"), NamedQuery(name = "DisJockeyInfo.deleteInactive", query = "DELETE FROM DisJockeyInfo m WHERE m.id = :id AND m.disEntityId IS NULL"))
data class DisJockeyInfo(
        @get:Id
        @get:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @get:Column(name = "ID")
        var id: Long,
        @get:Column(name = "RESERVATION_ID")
        var reservationId: String?,
        @get:Column(name = "NAME")
        var name: String?,
        @get:Column(name = "DIS_ENTITY_ID")
        var disEntityId: Long?,
        @get:java.beans.Transient
        @get:JsonIgnore
        @field:Transient
        var inetAddress: InetAddress?    
) : GenericEntity, Serializable {

    var inetAddressString: String?
        @Column(name = "INET_ADDRESS")
        @JsonProperty("inetAddress")
        get() = if (inetAddress != null) InetAddressWrapper(inetAddress).encodedInetAddress else null
        set(inetAddressString) {
            inetAddress = if (inetAddressString != null) InetAddressWrapper(inetAddressString).inetAddress else null
        }

    constructor() : this(id = 0L, reservationId = null, name = null, disEntityId = null, inetAddress = null) {}

    companion object {
        /** Serial version */
        private val serialVersionUID = 2027355982760360935L
    }
}
```

Comment: You're annotating the field instead of annotating the getter.

Comment: I have not been using Kotlin for very long, but I believe I put the `@Transient` annotation both on the field and on the getter: `@get:java.beans.Transient`.  That is what the `@get:` portion means, no?

Comment: Except the correct annotation is not java.beans.Transient, but javax.persistence.Transient

Comment: Yes! thank you! That is the answer -  if you put it in as an answer, I will accept and up-vote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're annotating the field instead of annotating the getter. Note that your getter annotation uses an incorrect type (`java.beans.Transient`) instead of the correct `javax.persistence.Transient`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Transient and import kotlin.jvm.Transient helped me.
(or just `@kotlin.jvm.Transient`)
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-transient/