# Kotlin Spring Boot - How do you skip a property in a class with CrudRepository?

Tags: spring, kotlin

hoping this is a easy question. How do you get the CrudRepository to skip making a field in the db table? i.e.

```
@Table
class Property(@Id val id: String?, val name: String, val objectType: String, currentValue: String?) {
}
```

lets say I only wanted a table with id & name created, skipping the others. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeking @Transient annotation.
Put the annotation above your field and Hibernate doesn’t persist it.

For more: [Kotlin, JPA and @Transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272844/kotlin-jpa-and-transient)

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but for some reason it's not working. Still produces this error:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "BYPASS" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO "PROPERTY" ("BYPASS", "CURRENT_VALUE", "NAME", "OBJECT_TYPE", "REDO_PROPERTY_HISTORY", "UNDO_PROPERTY_HISTORY") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-214]

but that may be due to something else i'm messing up! :)

Comment: Yeah this is another problem. There is no BYPASS field in your Property class. Also Undo.. Redo…

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to get it to work, but Transient is correct!

```
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
```